# Finding the limiting probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I found this problem in Shiryaev's *Problems* *in* *probability* (Problem 3.4.14).

> Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \dots$ be a sequence of independent and $N(0, 1)$-distributed random variables. Setting $S_n = \xi_1 + \dots + \xi_n, \;n \ge 1$, find the limiting probability distribution (as $n \rightarrow \infty $) of the random variables $$\frac1n \sum_{k= 2}^{n}|S_{k - 1}|(\xi_k^2 - 1), \quad n \ge 2.$$

Could anyone give me a hint for solving this?
Thank you!

Comment: Should the lower limit of the sum be $k = 1$ and what is $S_0$?

Comment: I suppose $S_0 = 0$. Fixed the limit

Comment: Then let the lower limit be $k = 2$ to avoid confusion.